# How do I enable modules in a Simpletest-Selenium test (Selenium module)?

Tags: 7, testing

I am using the [Selenium](https://www.drupal.org/project/selenium) module for Drupal, which is integrated with [SimpleTest](https://www.drupal.org/project/simpletest).

One thing I have not been able to do is to enable modules for the test cases. I am able to enable them on SimpleTest tests (using `setUp()`).

How do I enable modules in the Selenium Tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work completely the same. You should be able to enable modules passing arguments to setUp().

Implementation of the setUp() method for DrupalSeleniumWebTestCase is

```
protected function setUp() {
  $modules = func_get_args();
  parent::setUp($modules);
  //...
}
```

So everything passed to it is passed to parent setUp method that should enable modules for you.